# How to get Ethernet port and mac address of remote machine using java?

Tags: java, networking

I want to know number of Ethernet port present and their mac address of a remote server or switch. How do i do this? any idea ?

Comment: Ask the administrator of the remote server or switch

Comment: How would you do it without Java?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a machine you administrate yourself I would turn on SNMP-read privileges.
Gives you most information you might need.